# unhashable type: 'list' , why we use *?

Tags: python, list

I'm new to programming, and this solution for a problem, what exactly it's the role of *

```
def can_see_stage(seats):
    return all(sorted(set(row)) == list(row) for row in zip(*seats))
```

Answer (score 0):

Asterisk (iterable unpacking operator) used to *"unpack" list/tuple values*